# Convert ANT based NetBeans project to Gradle project?

Tags: netbeans, gradle, libraries

I have a NetBeans web project building Java, JS and HTML files. In order to get retrofit working to import a JSON API, I need to inject a dependency in a build.gradle file in the root of the project. I've written a headless build.gradle file, which I've tested and correctly handles the dependencies, how do I now change project to run from the build.gradle file instead of ANT everytime and searching through libraries?

Answer (score 4):

You need a build.gradle and settings.gradle file, and you have to delete the build.xml file (and maybe the nbproject/ directory)

I recommend making a gradle project using the netbeans gradle plugin and copying over and modifying the build.gradle file.

Then you need to add source sets in your build.gradle for where your sources are - gradle expects them in different place than netbeans ant puts them

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
    }
    resources {
      srcDir 'resources'
    }
  }

  test {
    java {
      srcDir 'test'
    }
    resources {
      srcDir 'testResources'
    }
  }
}
```

also, you need to make your dependencies. This is what mine looks like:

```
dependencies {
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10+'
  compile project(':logger')
  compile project(':postalker')
  compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.15+'
  compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4+'
  compile group: 'gov.nist.math', name: 'jama', version: '1.0.3+'
  compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-imaging', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT+'
  compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.5+'
  compile files( 'lib/jogl-runtime/jogl.jar')
  compile files( 'lib/gluegen-runtime/gluegen-rt.jar')
  compile files( 'lib/toxiclibscore.jar')
  compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.5+'
  compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.6'
  compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.1.3'
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.3.3'
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3.6'
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.6'
}
```

finally,
  I had to close the old project, shut netbeans down, then re-open netbeans and the project. Do a reload project and it was up and running!

for the person wondering how I got jogl working, I looked at what the jogl plugin did with ant and replicated it with gradle. I add a PlatformPrivate.gradle file that contains the developer's platform, then copy the appropriate libraries to the build directory

my entire build.gradle:

```
import com.protocase.files.FolderUtils
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import com.protocase.designer.extractors.BuildInfoExtractor
import com.protocase.designer.fileeditors.NSISInstallerModifier
import com.protocase.designer.fileeditors.SignBatModifier
import com.protocase.designer.ConfigureRun
import com.protocase.finders.FindFiles

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

apply from: "PlatformPrivate.gradle"
apply from: "Platforms.gradle"

sourceCompatibility = '1.6'

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.
//
// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'com.protocase.viewer.JDesigner'
}

if (! hasProperty('localPlatform')) {
  throw new GradleException("Missing PlatformPrivate.gradle");
}


mainClassName = ext.mainClass

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
            url "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
}

dependencies {
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10+'
  compile project(':logger')
  compile project(':postalker')
  compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.15+'
  compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4+'
  compile group: 'gov.nist.math', name: 'jama', version: '1.0.3+'
  compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-imaging', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT+'
  compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.5+'
  compile files( 'lib/jogl-runtime/jogl.jar')
  compile files( 'lib/gluegen-runtime/gluegen-rt.jar')
  compile files( 'lib/toxiclibscore.jar')
  compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.5+'
  compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.6'
  compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.1.3'
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.3.3'
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3.6'
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.6'
}

task copyDistLibs(type: Copy) {
  def outputDir = file("${buildDir}/libs")

  from configurations.runtime

  into outputDir
}

task updateBuildInfoBeta (type: Exec) {
  workingDir "${projectDir}/perl"
  commandLine './updateBuildInfo'
  def extractor = new BuildInfoExtractor(projectFile: new File("${projectDir}"))

  def version = extractor.getBetaVersion()

  def installerModifier = new NSISInstallerModifier(NSISFile: new File("${projectDir}/winRunFiles/JDesigner.nsi"))
  installerModifier.setOutputFileVersion(version)

  def signBatModifier = new SignBatModifier(signBatFile: new File("${projectDir}/sign.bat"))
  signBatModifier.setOutputFileVersion(version)

  println ""
  println "Making Beta Version: " + version
  println "branch: " + extractor.getReleaseVersion() + " date: " + extractor.getBuildDate()
  println ""
}

task makeBeta(dependsOn: updateBuildInfoBeta) {

  def distFolderLinux64 = makeOneDistBeta("linux-amd64")

  def ditsFolderLinux32 = makeOneDistBeta("linux-i586")

  def distFolderWin32 = makeOneDistBeta("windows-i586")
  FolderUtils.copyFolderContents(new File("${projectDir}/jre"), new File(distFolderWin32, "jre"))
  FolderUtils.copyFolderContents(new File("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/library"), new File(distFolderWin32, "library"))
  FolderUtils.copyFolderContents(new File("${projectDir}/winRunFiles"), distFolderWin32)
  Files.copy(Paths.get("${projectDir}/license.txt"), Paths.get(new File(distFolderWin32, "license.txt").path))
  Files.copy(Paths.get("${projectDir}/Protocase Designer.ico"), Paths.get(new File(distFolderWin32, "Protocase Designer.ico").path))


  def distFolderMac = makeOneDistBeta("macosx-universal")

}

private File makeOneDistBeta(def nativePlatform) {
  def plat = new com.protocase.designer.Platform(natives: nativePlatform, libFolder: 'lib', genericBuildDir: new File("${buildDir}"))
  println plat.getNativeDistDir()
  plat.makeAndPopulateBuildDir()
  plat.copyLibraryFiles()
  plat.getNativeDistDir()

}


makeBeta.dependsOn(jar)
makeBeta.dependsOn(copyDistLibs)

task makeWin32Beta(dependsOn: makeBeta, type: Exec) {
  def wineDir = new File("${projectDir}/../../.wine/drive_c/")
  println wineDir.exists()
  def nsisFile = FindFiles.findFirstFileByNameWithoutDirectory(wineDir, "makensis.exe", "users")
  println nsisFile.path

  def MAKENSIS = nsisFile.getPath().replaceFirst("(.*)drive_c/", "c:\\\\")
  println MAKENSIS
  MAKENSIS = MAKENSIS.replaceAll("/","\\\\")

  def extractor = new BuildInfoExtractor(projectFile: new File("${projectDir}"))
  def version = extractor.getBetaVersion()

  workingDir "${buildDir}/windows-i586"


  def fullCommand = 'WINEDEBUG=fixme-win,fixme-sync,fixme-heap /usr/bin/wine "' + MAKENSIS + '" /V1 /DVER_STR=' + version + ' /X"SetCompressor /FINAL lzma" ./JDesigner.nsi'

  println "makensis command:"
  println MAKENSIS
  println fullCommand
  println ""

  commandLine fullCommand
}



private void configureRun (def task) {
  apply from: 'PlatformPrivate.gradle'
  def confRun = new ConfigureRun(localPlatform: localPlatform)

  confRun.configureRun(task, mainClass, sourceSets)
}

run {
  configureRun(it)
}

task(debug, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
  configureRun(it)
  debug = true
}
```

The PlatformPrivate.gradle

```
ext {
  localPlatform='linux-amd64'
}
```

com.protocase.designer.Platform:

```
package com.protocase.designer

import com.protocase.files.FolderUtils
import org.gradle.api.GradleException
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

public class Platform {
  def natives
  def libFolder
  def genericBuildDir

  String gluegenDir() {
     def dirName = 'gluegen-rt.jar-natives-' + natives
     dirName
  }

  String joglDir() {
    def dirName = "jogl.jar-natives-" + natives
    dirName
  }

  def getExtension() {
    def result = ""
    switch (natives)
    {
      case 'linux-amd64':
      case 'linux-i586':
      case 'solaris-i586':
      case 'solaris-sparc':
      case 'solaris-sparcv9':
        result = 'so'
        break;

      case 'macosx-universal':
      case 'macosx-ppc':
        result = 'jnilib'
        break;

      case 'windows-i586':
      case 'windows-amd64':
        result = 'dll'
        break;

      default:
        throw new GradleException ('programmer missed a case or bad platform: ' + natives)
    }

    result
  }

  def getNativeDistDir() {
    def buildDir = new File(genericBuildDir, natives)
  }

  def makeAndPopulateBuildDir() {
    def sourceDir = new File(genericBuildDir, 'libs')
    def nativeDistDir = getNativeDistDir()

    if (nativeDistDir.exists()) {
      FolderUtils.deleteFolder(nativeDistDir)
    }

    FolderUtils.copyFolderContents(sourceDir, nativeDistDir)
  }

  def getLibraryDirs() {
    def dirList = []

    def dir = new File(new File(libFolder, "gluegen-runtime"), gluegenDir())

    dirList << dir

    dir = new File(new File(libFolder, "jogl-runtime"), joglDir())

    dirList << dir

    dirList
  }

  def getLibraryFiles() {
    def fileList = []

    def dirs = getLibraryDirs()

    dirs.each {
      it.eachFile(FILES) {
    file -> fileList << file
      }
    }

    fileList
  }

  def copyLibraryFiles() {

    def copyOptions = [StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES]
    def destinationFolder = new File(getNativeDistDir(), 'lib')

    getLibraryDirs().each {
      FolderUtils.copyFolderContents(it, destinationFolder)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I am having problems getting jogl and gradle working together, I see in your `dependencies` you use it... do you mind showing the full `build.gradle`?

Comment: I added my full build.gradle and a couple of the other gradle files I made. If I missed anything, let me know.

Comment: Please take care as he uses JOGL 1, you see jogl.jar above whereas it's called jogl-all.jar in JOGL 2. JOGL 1 is obsolete and not maintained since about 5 years, it's time to switch to JOGL 2.

Comment: However if you've been using JOGL 1 for a long time, it still works! The principle would be the same for JOGL 2.